# aframe a-physics detect collision b/w 2 static bodies

Tags: javascript, aframe

Hi I am new to aframe and trying to do collision detection b/w 2 bodies which have the component of static-body attached with them.

I don't why the event collide is not being fired as its working fine b/w 1 dynamic and 1 static body but not working with 2 static bodies.

Kindly suggest a way to detect collision b/w 2 static-bodies using aphysics or if there is any other way let me know.

I am moving the static body using `setInterval()` and changing its position using `setAttribute('position','x y z');`

Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the  [a-frame physics documentation](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system):

> static-body: A fixed-position or animated object. Other objects may
>   collide with static bodies, but static bodies themselves are
>   unaffected by gravity and collisions.

Static bodies are unaffected by collisions.

---

If they can't be dynamic, I would suggest tracking their position + volume on tick and checking if they are colliding ( should be easy for primitive objects ).

If You have two spheres (s(x1,y1,z1) and s2(x2,y2,z2)), You can add a master component in the scene checking their distance from each other using a simple distance between 2 points [formula](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html):

```
 tick:function(){
   if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x1-x2),2) + Math.pow((y1-y2),2) + Math.pow((z1-z2),2)))<(sRadius+s2Radius)){
   //do stuff when spheres collide
   }
 }
```

From what i see, three.js has its own intersect methods, You can find them [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Box3) ( methods: `intersect()`, `intersectsBox()`,etc...). To access the three.js object, get the `el.object3D` reference.

The intersection object is defined like this:

```
{ distance, point, face, faceIndex, indices, object }
distance – distance between the origin of the ray and the intersection
point – point of intersection, in world coordinates
face – intersected face
faceIndex – index of the intersected face
indices – indices of vertices comprising the intersected face
object – the intersected object
```

as explained in the [three.js documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Raycaster).

For intersection of other primitives, You'll need to research algorithms for intersections, as the algorithms i have in my mind are highly inefficient.

Comment: can you tell me how to build that component maybe a pseudo code will help Thanks.....

Comment: @user287332 updated, is it okay, or You need more information ?

Comment: Thanks your answer put me in the right direction.... I am using this in the component's tick: function(){    firstBB = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(matchingElements[i].object3D);
      secondBB = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.el.object3D);
      var collision = firstBB.intersectsBox(secondBB);
      
      if(collision){
     this.el.emit('collision', {value: 2, el: this.el});

Comment: @user287332 glad I could help, happy coding !